# Linux - "grep" from certain lines to the end of file

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a text file similar to this:

```
line 1
line 2A
line 3
line 4A
line 5
```

I want to "grep" from "line 2A" to the end of file, something like this

```
cat file.txt|some_grep "line 2A"
```

Also, I want to "grep" from "line 2A" to the next line that contains "A", something like this

```
cat file.txt| some_grep "A"
```

I want this to print out:

```
line 2A
line 3
line 4A
```

Which command can help me achieve this?

Comment: The first is the exact case that is trivial for awk range patterns `awk '/line 2A/,0'` and the second can be `awk '/line 2A/,/A/&&!/line 2A/'` or if it's at least one char before the A `awk '/line 2A/,/[^2]A/'`

Comment: Thank you, if you could turn this into an answer, I'll mark it as it as the...answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(expanded from comment)

`awk` has a capability to select 'ranges' of lines which matches this need perfectly, as [described in the the GNU-awk (gawk) manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Ranges). (This feature works in other `awk`s but the `gawk` manual is easy to link.)

`awk '/line 2A/,0'` prints lines starting with the first one that matches `line 2A` and continuing until the end of input because `0` is a condition that is never true.

`awk '/line 2A/,/A/&&!/line 2A/'` starts printing with a line that matches `line 2A` and stops after a line that matches `A` but NOT `line 2A` (and thus cannot be the same line as the starting line). It will start *again* on a *subsequent* `line 2A` and so on; if you want to prevent that there are slightly more complicated ways to do so.

If the stopping lines always have some character other than `2` before the `A` this can be simplified to `awk '/line 2A/,/[^2]A/'` which stops after a line that matches any character other than 2, followed by A. You might want a variation of this, e.g. to stop on any-single-digit-A different from 2A, but not other As like `WHAT`; for that the stopping condition might be `,/line [013-9]A/`.

Answer (score 17):

> I want to "grep" from "line 2A" to the end of file:

```
sed -n '/2A/,$p'
```

- -n   : suppress `sed` default output
- /2A/ : output lines from the first one containing "2A"
- $    : to end of file

> I want to "grep" from "line 2A" to the next line that contains "A":

```
sed -n '/2A/,/A/p'
```

- /A/  : output until a line contains "A"

> I want to "grep" from the first line containing "A" to the next one:

```
printf "/A\n.+1,/A/p\nq" | ed -s
```

---

```
$ > foo echo "line 1
line 2A
line 3
line 4A
line 5"

$ sed -n '/2A/,$p' foo
line 2A
line 3
line 4A
line 5

$ sed -n '/2A/,/A/p' foo
line 2A
line 3
line 4A

$ printf "/A\n.+1,/A/p\nq" | ed -s foo
line 2A
line 3
line 4A
```

Comment: There is an hint in the question `some_grep "A"` which suggests OP wants smallest range of lines between two containing "A". Defining the range from /2A/ to /A/ is a specific case and a workaround rather than an answer.

Comment: @techrat I'm answering to the question that I quoted in my reply. Granted there is a contradiction with the parameter passed. Answer updated.

Comment: Unfortunately `sed -n '/A/,/A/p'` is a wrong answer. Try it with an input file with more than two lines containing "A".

Comment: @techraf Indeed, answer updated again.

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way is to use `grep` in combination with `cut` and `tail`. First, use grep to get the line on which the desired string is (`-n` to output line number; `-m 1` to stop searching after the first match):

`grep -n -m 1 "somestring" filename.txt`

This outputs the line number and the string itself. To cut away the string, we use cut (`-f1`: output first field; `-d:` use ":" as delimiter):

`grep -n -m 1 "somestring" filename.txt | cut -f1 -d:`

Next, we use the output of this command as parameter in tail. Normally, tail prints the last k lines, but using `-n +k`, we get tail to print from line k onwards. The total command is:

```
tail -n +`grep -n -m 1 "somestring" filename.txt | cut -f1 -d:` filename.txt
```

To output the lines until `somestring` use `head` instead of `tail` and `-n -#` instead of `-n +#`. You could also combine both to get the lines from one string until another.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the size maximum number of lines in the file, you can also use `grep -A NUM "line 2A"` or `grep --after-context=NUM "line 2A"`, which prints NUM lines of trailing context after matching line 2A.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below -

```
sed -n '6,$p' infile
```

Comment: Can you turn this into a "teachable moment" by expanding your answer to explain the command?  Thanks.

Comment: This ignores conditions specified by OP in first and (even after modification) does not answer the second problem: *from "line 2A" to the next line that contains "A"*.

Answer (score 0):

The sed method is the way to go, but what if you want to keep the top lines, but not grep them?

Here's a way:

```
{ head -1 file.txt ; sed 1d file.txt | grep <whatever> ;}
```

What's going on here?

First, we spit out the top line (head -1 file.txt)
Then, we remove the top line (sed 1d file.txt) and grep just that.

The whole thing is wrapped by { .. ;}, so you can pipe or redirect both the header and the grepped body together afterward.  Like this:

{ head -1 file.txt ; sed 1d file.txt | grep  ;} > newfile.txt

If you want to skip the first 10 lines, change it to this

{ head -10 file.txt ; sed 1,10d file.txt | grep  ;}